# How can I trust that the proofreader and designer of a book will not plagiarize our work?

Tags: copyright, book, plagiarism, proofreading

My friend and I are writing a book in English in the Electrical Engineering field. At this stage, we need someone to proofread our texts and also to design the layout of the book, so we will need to entrust them with our manuscript. I was wondering, how can we trust that the proofreader and designer of the book will not plagiarize our work?

Comment: Register your work with the US Copyright Office: https://www.google.de/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_registration

Comment: That's interesting. But it raised some questions:1) I don't live in U.S, But I want to publish it international, So Can I still Register there? 2) Do I need to finish the manuscript of the book before restringing it, in other word, Can I register the draft of some parts of book there?@what

Comment: Yes and yes. You can also pay a notary in your home country.

Answer (score 6):

Work with reputable proofreaders and designers, who have proven track records with satisfied clients.

Anybody with a reputation to maintain will have no profit from plagiarizing clients' work. First of all, a manuscript on its own isn't worth a whole lot (it takes a lot of work to earn good money off a manuscript), and secondly, they'll stop getting clients.

Comment: Working with people you don't trust is a bad idea to begin with. A much more common problem is simply getting work on your book that isn't very good.

Comment: How can you find reputable proofreaders and designers?

Comment: Same way you find a reputable plumber. Ask for recommendations; google for recommendations; google for the type of job you want done, and then check out reviews of the names you get.

Comment: With books it's actually fairly easy, because the final product is usually made public. If you're looking for a cover designer, they should ALWAYS be able to point you to books they've already designed covers for.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to "Work with reputable proofreaders and designers," as Standback correctly notes, you can also add a non-disclosure agreement to your contract. The language might state that the contents/cover/etc. of the book is to remain strictly confidential until official publication by X publishing house or Y printer.

Honestly, I don't think this is something you need to worry about. Any proofreader or designer who plagiarized clients would be out of business the next day. Nobody is going to work with someone who steals from the client. It's utterly self-defeating.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question if you intend to publish your book with an established publisher or in an independent way.

In scientific fields, proofreading is typically done, at least partly, by colleagues who know the subject. Here confidentiality is commonly guaranteed by trust. Then there is the publisher's editor. Here confidentiality is guaranteed by the contract.

The book design should typically follow the publisher's style, which can depend on the book series. Many scientific publishers distribute style guides and LaTeX classes to their authors. If you want to follow your own design you should probably make an agreement with the publisher.

Finally, take into account that the yearly income which can result from selling a scientific book is typically very limited and hiring a professional proofreader and a designer can be onerous.

Comment: I am trying to design the book in my way with Adobe-Indesign software. I dont like to follow publishers style. so, I must print it out at a Printery and register it myself. I am familiar with designing and graphic process so I can do most of it.But, I must take care of proofreading too. So I was thinking to engage an undergraduate student to proofread my book and in return I give the the Editor credit. So, I was worry about plagiarism as we may not have any physical contact. @massimo-ortolano

Comment: Then ask him to sign an NDA. I'm perplexed, however, by the approach you've chosen to publish.

Comment: Thanks, so where can he sign a NDA in U.S, a notary? Why are you perplexed man? @massimo-ortolano

Comment: @Electricman: I'm not from US, so I can't give you advice on how to find a notary there. If you are affiliated to an institution you might ask to the legal office, maybe the NDA can be signed under the umbrella of the institution.